# Ionic Sidemenu and Native Google Maps

Tags: cordova, google-maps, ionic-framework

I am developing an Ionic application where I'm using the side-menu. When navigating to a template that's only a div for rendering Google Maps (native using cordova-plugin-maps). The side-menu is overlayed over the map. The weird thing is I can interact with the map through the side-menu.

It works fine when using Javascript Google Maps.

Here's a screenshot of how it looks:

[image]

The same thing appears on an Android device.

The help in resolving is highly appreciated!!

**EDIT:**
I forgot to mention that I'm transitioning from a normal page (not the side-menu), hence the back button above. I hope that makes it more specific.

Comment: hi, you found a solution?

Comment: Yes. I have added an answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found it FINALLY!!

You have to hide the `<ion-side-menu>` when transitioning to the map. For example (what I did):

```
document.getElementById("side-menu").style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

When transitioning away from the map, inside the $stateChangeSuccess callback, set it back to `"visible"`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Could you create an explain wiki page with sample code in the maps plugin wiki page? https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/wiki

Comment: Sure! Find the wiki here: https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/wiki/Ionic-Side-Menu-with-the-plugin

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 5):

This works for me: 
1. Place ng-hide to

```
<ion-side-menu side="left" data-ng-hide="hideLeft">
```

2. watch the $ionicSideMenuDelegate in menu controller

`// hack sidemenu overlay
            $scope.$watch(function () {
                return $ionicSideMenuDelegate.getOpenRatio();
            }, function (newValue, oldValue) {
                if (newValue == 0) {
                    $scope.hideLeft = true;
                } else {
                    $scope.hideLeft = false;
                }
            });`

Answer (score 2):

scss ionic.app.scss or www/csss/

```
body.menu-open .menu.menu-left {
    visibility: visible;
}
.menu.menu-left {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you could actually set it like this:

Map

`<ion-item nav-clear menu-close ng-click="fuction to call the map page">`

or

```
<ion-item nav-clear menu-close ui-sref="url to page">
```

*when you click on Map in menu the side menu closes and the page gets displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I found an elegant solution (right menu) :

```
.menu.menu-right {
    transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0) !important;
    -webkit-transition: transform 200ms ease;
    transition: transform 200ms ease;
}

.menu-open {
    .menu.menu-right {
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) !important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need changed type for default on tag `ion-menu`

```
<ion-menu type="reveal" [content]="content">
...
...
...
</ion-menu>
```

Comment: My question isn't using Ionic 2

Answer (score 0):

Because the map of cordova-google-maps plugin follows the mapDiv position.

The ionic-framework creates the side menu **under the map div.**

You should create the side menu **above the map div.**

Check out here.
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/using-google-maps-cordova-plugin/4456/49

[image]

Comment: I checked the forum thread, no one seems to put a direct answer. Can you please show me the code of how to fix this?